Preventing TabView from capturing some swipe gestures on the first tab with nested ListView swipe callbacks
I am working on a flutter application with a three-tab screen.
On the first tab, I have a custom view of a package that has a ListView where each Row has a swipe gesture callback (swipe from left to right). The TabView also has a swipe gesture to change tabs (with full animation).
My issue is that the TabView is capturing the swipe from left to right gestures on the first tab even though there is no tab to the left to navigate to. This prevents the Row in the ListView from detecting the swipe and firing its callback. I want to retain the tab-swipe feature while allowing the row swipe callback to work.
Here is the setup I have:

A TabView with three tabs.
The first tab contains a PackageView which includes a ListView. Each ListView item is designed to detect a left-to-right swipe and trigger an event.
I need the left to right swipe on the first tab to be passed through the TabView to the ListView without the TabView capturing it.

Here's a diagram:

And here's a link to a video:
Video showcasing the issue
How can I prevent the TabView from interfering with the swipe gesture on the first tab, allowing the ListView item to detect and respond to the swipe correctly?
To resolve the issue, I attempted to disable swipe gestures on the first tab by setting scrollPhysics to NeverScrollableScrollPhysics, and then I wrapped the first tab's content in a GestureDetector to manually handle swipes, but it did not work.
Here's a code to reproduce the issue:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
          bottom: TabBar(
            controller: tabController,
            tabs: const [
              Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
              Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
              Tab(text: 'Tab 3'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          // Uncomment next line to see the expected behavior but keeping the swipe to tab2 gesture enabled
          // physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          controller: tabController,
          children: [
            MyTabContent(),
            const Center(child: Text('Tab 2')),
            const Center(child: Text('Tab 3')),
          ],
        ));
  }
}

class MyTabContent extends StatelessWidget {
  final list = List.generate(30, (index) => 'Item $index');

  MyTabContent({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: list.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ItemRow(item: list[index]);
      },
    );
  }
}

class ItemRow extends StatefulWidget {
  final String item;

  const ItemRow({
    Key? key,
    required this.item,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ItemRowState createState() => _ItemRowState();
}

class _ItemRowState extends State<ItemRow> {
  double? startHorizontalDrag;
  double? currentHorizontalDrag;
  double translateX = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onPanStart: (details) {
        startHorizontalDrag = details.localPosition.dx;
      },
      onPanUpdate: (details) {
        setState(() {
          currentHorizontalDrag = details.localPosition.dx;
          translateX = currentHorizontalDrag! - startHorizontalDrag!;

          if (translateX < 0) translateX = 0;
        });
      },
      onPanEnd: (_) {
        if (translateX >= 50) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Swipe right")));
        }
        setState(() => translateX = 0.0);
      },
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(translateX, 0),
            child: ListTile(title: Text(widget.item)),
          ),
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Opacity(
                  opacity: (translateX > 20 ? (translateX - 20) / 30 : 0).clamp(0.0, 1.0).toDouble(),
                  child: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}



The question quite is clear but it would be nice to include minimal-reproducible-example

@Md.YeasinSheikh just added code that reproduces the issue, thanks.

The issue you're encountering is that the GestureDetector within the ItemRow widget is capturing the horizontal drag events, preventing the TabBarView from responding to them for tab switching.
To fix this, you can modify the GestureDetector to conditionally handle the drag events based on whether the drag is primarily horizontal or not. Here's how you can update your GestureDetector:
GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  onHorizontalDragStart: (details) {
    startHorizontalDrag = details.localPosition.dx;
  },
  onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
    final dx = details.localPosition.dx;
    if (startHorizontalDrag == null) {
      startHorizontalDrag = dx;
    }
    setState(() {
      currentHorizontalDrag = dx;
      translateX = currentHorizontalDrag! - startHorizontalDrag!;
      if (translateX < 0) translateX = 0;
    });
  },
  onHorizontalDragEnd: (_) {
    if (translateX >= 50) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Swipe right")));
    }
    setState(() => translateX = 0.0);
  },
  child: Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: [
      Transform.translate(
        offset: Offset(translateX, 0),
        child: ListTile(title: Text(widget.item)),
      ),
      Positioned.fill(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Opacity(
              opacity: (translateX > 20 ? (translateX - 20) / 30 : 0).clamp(0.0, 1.0).toDouble(),
              child: const Icon(Icons.delete),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)


By using onHorizontalDragStart, onHorizontalDragUpdate, and onHorizontalDragEnd, we specifically handle horizontal drag events while letting vertical drag events pass through to the parent widgets for tab switching. Also, setting behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent allows gestures to be detected even when they occur over transparent parts of the widget.

I've just added code that reproduces the issue.

I've solved the problem you were facing! Now check please I've written a descriptive answer.

While on the Tab1 the swipe from left to right works and shows the icon, the swipe from right to left to switch to Tab2 does not work.
The result is the same as applying the NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() to the TabBarView
